# Why doesn't setuid on /sbin/dhclient work as intended?

Tags: command-line, networking, setuid

I am the only user on my machine, and prefer not to type `sudo` every time I use `dhclient`. Therefore, I tried `sudo chmod u+s /sbin/dhclient`.

However, when I subsequently run `dhclient wlan0` from a non-root shell, I still get `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

I am running `Ubuntu 13.10`.

Why does setting the `UID` bit not achieve the desired effect, and are there any workarounds?

Comment: Try `sudo chmod u+s /sbin/ip` as well. `dhclient` runs the shell script `/usr/sbin/dhclient-script`, and shells invoked with uid != euid generally drop their privileges down to the uid. The error message you see, according to my testing, is from `/sbin/ip`, which is run by the shell script and thus with your (non-root) uid.

Answer (score 1):

sudo sets both the real and effective uids.  Making an executable setuid only causes the effective uid to be set when the executable is run.  If the executable juggles uids to fork unprivileged children as dhclient does, you can easily trip it up by running it with a non-root real uid.

A workaround would be to write a wrapper executable that does nothing but set the real uid to match the effective uid and then run dhclient.  Make the wrapper setuid root and remove the setuid bit from dhclient.

Comment: how would the wrapper executable set the real uid? 
Would the wrapper simply say `sudo dhclient`?

Comment: I'm assuming a C program which would call setreuid(), then execve().